# batchPath for Members insert api

Tags: google-api, google-admin-sdk

We would like to insert group members via batch job.
URL for single request is following

https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/groups/groupKey/members

Currently we are using following url for batch
https://www.googleapis.com/batch

But as per blog
https://developers.googleblog.com/2018/03/discontinuing-support-for-json-rpc-and.html

> Change the endpoint from www.googleapis.com/batch to
>   www.googleapis.com/batch/<api>/<version>

What is updated batchPatch for insert group members via batch request

Comment: Can you post the code you are currently using.   If you are using one of Googles offical libraries they most likely already have support for what you are talking about.

Comment: We are using as example given at url - https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/batch